# How to get the amount of files and classes from image_dataset_from_directory in keras?

Tags: python, keras, tensor

Using [`image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) to load images in colab we receive a feedback how many files and classes we have in the dataset.

In my case I receive the following message: "Found 8686 files belonging to 101 classes."

I use the following code:

```
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  IM_DIR,
  labels='inferred', #'inferred', None
  label_mode='int',  #'int', 'categorical', 'binary' or None
  class_names=None,
  color_mode='rgb',  #'grayscale', 'rgb' or 'rgba'
  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
  image_size=(IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH),
  shuffle=True,
  seed=51719,
  validation_split=None,
  subset=None,                #'training', 'validation' or 'both'
  interpolation='bilinear',   #'bilinear', 'nearest', 'bicubic', 'area', 'lanczos3', 'lanczos5', 'gaussian' or 'mitchellcubic'
  follow_links=False,
  crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
)
```

I'd like to know if is it possible to "get" this information about the amount of files and classes **directly** as variables.

Today I get the amount of files using following code:

```
#list images
#file extensions
im_ext = ['.jpg', '.JPG', '.jpeg', '.JPEG', '.png', '.PNG']

#get images
def get_im(IM_DIR):
  im_list = []
  i = 1
  for root, directories, files in os.walk(IM_DIR):
    for file in files:
      if any(ext in file for ext in im_ext):
        im_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        i += 1
  return im_list

im_names = sorted(get_im(IM_DIR))
im_total = len(im_names)
print(f'total number of images = {im_total}')
```

And with that I have the same number of files: 8686, but if we could extract the information somehow from the `image_dataset_from_directory` above it would be much more efficient.

Comment: It should be something like `dataset.samples` or `dataset.filenames` for images, and `dataset.classes` for classes. That will be an array, so you can just call `len()` on whichever. That's how it's done in the source code, at least.

Comment: @Djinn, it works to ```tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory``` (that is deprecated), but not to ```tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory```

Comment: It's `dataset.class_names` and `dataset.file_paths`. Call `len()` on both. You can also debug to find this.

Comment: @Djinn thanks, it worked. Could you please tell me how to debug?